# Healpy Plotting

Tags: plot, healpy

I'm very new to this, but I have been given a .fits file that I've plotted with healpy using this code.

```
map = hp.read_map('.fits')
hp.mollview(map, title=fileName,min=-1,max=1)
hp.graticule()
plt.show()
```

I'd like to zoom into the coordinates RA = [-50,50] and Dec = [-70,-45].

How can I do this? I only see the options for rotating the map, not zooming in on an area. 
Am I misunderstanding something?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot zoom in Mollweide projection, you should use a Gnomonic projection instead:

```
hp.gnomview(map, rot=[colatitude_deg, longitude_deg])
```

you can change `xsize` and `reso` to change the width of the projected area.

Comment: I just discovered cart view, would it be better? I'm actually not sure how to translate RA and Dec values to latitude and longitude. Are they the same?

Comment: you can also use `cartview`, if your map is already in Equatorial coordinates then RA is the same as longitude, Dec is 90 - colatitude